# While C Arduino can't looping (With statement), Using MQTT

Tags: c

i use esp8266, raspberry and MQTT. i work this project for graduation on my university.

```
uint32_t start = millis();
  while (millis() - start < 500) {
  if ((char)payload[0]=='m'){
    client.connected();
  long memory = ESP.getFreeHeap();
    char mem[16];

    sprintf(mem,"Status memory1 : %d Kb",memory);
    client.publish("esp8266",mem);
    return;
  }
}
if((char)payload[0]=='s'){
    client.publish("esp8266", "Hello Raspberry Pi");
    client.disconnect();
}
```

when i run that's code, at statement 'm' esp8266 only send once "status memory" to raspberry and not looping. why "while" does not send repeatedly and continuously until the next statement is received.

i'm sorry if my english so bad, i need solution, Please Help me. Thank's

Comment: As I understand your question, you code runs once _(write "Status memory")_ and then exit. This is caused by the `return` statement. When the code should loop, remove `return`.

Comment: thank's for your answer Julo, i just tried your solution to remove return, but the code still not looping.

Answer (score 0):

I see there more errors:

1. `return` terminates the code after the first run of `payload[0] == 'm'`
2. Small buffer:

The text `"Status memory1 :  Kb"` *(without `%d`)* is 20 characters long.
But the `char mem[16]` defines only a 16 character long buffer. That means, there will be a overflow.
It is not possible to determine what will happen after this error. It can overwrite the `start`,
or even the position of return and can cause the application to crash *(execute code that should not be executed)*.

Fixed code:

```
uint32_t start = millis();
while (millis() - start < 500) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == 'm') {
    client.connected();
    long memory = ESP.getFreeHeap();
    char mem[32]; // updated value from 16 to 32

    sprintf(mem, "Status memory1 : %d Kb", memory);
    client.publish("esp8266", mem);
    // removed return
  }
}

if ((char)payload[0]=='s')
{
  client.publish("esp8266", "Hello Raspberry Pi");
  client.disconnect();
}
```

3. I'm not sure, whether the position of `client.connected();` and `client.disconnect();` are correct. This depends on unknown factors, but it is possible, that these function should be placed before *(connect)*, or after (disconnect) the code in this example.

Comment: thank's for answer again @Julo, i apologize for late respon because maybe our country have a different time.

the code still not looping, but if i use (!='m') the code can looping. 
The problem is my statement more than 2.
so i cant use that statement (!='m').

i still dont know why, if i use (=='m') the code cant looping, and if i use (!='m') the code can looping.

Comment: @inungbagusprasetyo No problem _(there is almost always a time difference between people)_. I'm not an expert on Arduino/MQTT/Raspberry. _(I saw this question only because it was in wrong category.)_ Nor do I understand the meaning of the code _(what values are in `payload[]`, how do they change, etc.)_. Now, there is only one think you can do. Debugging. Since debugging with time limits is hard, try to add some debug log output messages _(to file/serial port)_ and see what is in the `payload[0]`, how long it takes the cycle to run, etc.